# Passing a Camera from one screen to another on dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera

I recently started coding on flutter and dart and Im trying to learn it. While developing an app I was trying to link one button on my first screen to another screen where I launch the camera in order to take a photo.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before 'runApp()'
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      title: "Ipm-p2",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Ipm-p2")),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(firstCamera),
      ),
      /*TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),*/
    ),
  );
}
```

MyStatelessWidget is my first screen where I have the button that launchs the camera:

```
/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget(CameraDescription firstCamera, {Key key, this.camera}) : super(key: key);

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TakePictureScreen(camera: this.camera))
              );
            },
            child: const Text('Enabled Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I launch the app and tap the button it takes me to the camera screen but the camera just wont work. How do I need to pass the firstCamera in order to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1->** Add the required dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera:
  path_provider:
  path:
```

**Step 2->** Get a list of the available cameras.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

// Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
final cameras = await availableCameras();
// Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
final firstCamera = cameras.first;
```

**Step 3->** Create and initialize the CameraController.

This process establishes a connection to the device’s camera that allows you to control the camera and display a preview of the camera’s feed.

```
// A screen that takes in a list of cameras and the Directory to store images.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    final CameraDescription camera;

    const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
      }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  // Add two variables to the state class to store the CameraController and
  // the Future.
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Fill this out in the next steps.
  }
}
```

**Step 4->** Use a CameraPreview to display the camera’s feed.

You can use the CameraController to take pictures using the takePicture() method. In this example, create a FloatingActionButton that takes a picture using the CameraController when a user taps on the button.

**Step 5->** Take a picture with the CameraController.

You can use the CameraController to take pictures using the takePicture() method. In this example, create a FloatingActionButton that takes a picture using the CameraController when a user taps on the button.

```
FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
  // Provide an onPressed callback.
  onPressed: () async {
    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
    // catch the error.
    try {
      // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
      await _initializeControllerFuture;

      // Construct the path where the image should be saved using the path
      // package.
      final path = join(
        // Store the picture in the temp directory.
        // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );

      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved.
      await _controller.takePicture(path);
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
      print(e);
    }
  },
)
```

**Step 6->** Display the picture with an Image widget.

If you take the picture successfully, you can then display the saved picture using an Image widget. In this case, the picture is stored as a file on the device.

```
Image.file(File('path/to/my/picture.png'))
```

Comment: This is straigth up copy and pasted from another site and not what Im asking